# Linked List Nodes in Python

Tags: python, recursion, nodes

I am working on linked list python code (see code below), and I can't for the life of me work out why when the condition check_value == search_term is clearly True the function does not return that.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hpmp.jpg

You can see that the print statement for the fifth iteration shows that the statement is True, but the function overall evaluates to False. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
class LinkedListNode:
def __init__(self, value, next_node = None):
    self.value = value
    self.next_node = next_node

def linked_list_search(node, search_term):
    check_value = node.value
    next_node = node.next_node
    
    if not next_node == None:
        next_node_value = next_node.value
        
        if check_value == search_term:
            return True
        else:
            
            linked_list_search(node.next_node, search_term)
    
    if check_value == search_term:
        
        return True
    
    
    return False

#Below are lines of code that create a linked list,
#and then search for two values in that linked list:
#one that is there, one that isn't. If your function
#works, it should print True then False.
node_7 = LinkedListNode(5)
node_6 = LinkedListNode(2, node_7)
node_5 = LinkedListNode(9, node_6)
node_4 = LinkedListNode(1, node_5)
node_3 = LinkedListNode(4, node_4)
node_2 = LinkedListNode(6, node_3)
root_node = LinkedListNode(7, node_2)

print(linked_list_search(root_node, 9))
print(linked_list_search(root_node, 3))
```

Thanks in advance.

Update: Apologies for original post. I wanted to show the output, which is why I included an image. Code is now included.

Thank you for the replies.

Comment: Please post your code here and not images.

Comment: You have written a recursive code and you are missing one of the base condition also else part should also have return statement as `John Coleman` mentioned in the comment. That's why overall response is False and result will be always unpredictable. Post a minimal code instead of image, then you will get response faster :).

Comment: I think it should be OK now (hopefully). Thanks to your advice, it now works. Apologies again for the original post. Thank you very much.

Comment: It still doesn't work. It is missing the class definition now and the body of the function isn't indented.

Comment: I think *this* is how you intended to format it?

Comment: Anyway, it works for me (assuming I supply a trivial definition of `LinkedListNode`): I get `True` for `9` and `False` for `3`, which is as I expect.

Comment: You have now changed the code so that it no longer matches the code in the image and no longer has the same issue. This makes your question a moving target.

Comment: Sorry, one of the earlier versions (not the first few) did have the body of the function, but then it was lost. By the time I added it back, my updated version included the amendment that made the function work. I have now removed that amendment again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the linked_list_search in a lot simpler way.

```
def linked_list_search(node, search_term):
    # Iterate through list till you reach the tail of the list
    while(node):
        if(node.value == search_term):
            # Return True as soon as you find the search_term
            return True
        # Assign node to the next node in the list 
        node = node.next
    # Return False if search_term not found in the linked_list
    return False
```